# iPhone development: How to implement HTTPS connection?

Tags: iphone, ssl, https

I am working on an iPhone project which need to connect to the IIS server over HTTPS or SSL protocol. Can anyone tell me how to implement HTTPS connection in iPhone? Any advice would be appreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just a note: no need to put iPhone dev in the title, it's already in the tags

Answer (score 2):

Ben Copsey's [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) framework makes it trivially easy to issue web requests over SSL.

Modifying the site's example slightly:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://allseeing-i.com"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSLog (@"%@", response);
}
```

Comment: So ASIHTTPRequest recognize the https site and encrypts the data? Is this right?

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest has been deprecated. See: http://allseeing-i.com/ and search on "[request release]"

Comment: Thanks I already know about that, but I've worked with ASIHTTPRequest so far and I want to complete that app with ASIHTTPRequest. So answer my question above. Big Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use NSURLConnection with an NSURLRequest pointing to an NUSUL with https protocol, just like that:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mySecureServer.net"]];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (!error) {
    //do something with response & data
}
```

But I suggest you have a look at the documentation of the [URL loading system](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) in Cocoa.

Comment: Hi stigi, 

Thanks for your helping. And I have read the documentation of the URL loading system in Cocoa. But I'm still struggling with the HTTPS issue. I have changed my code like the above. But the clause "!error" are always not true which indicates that there must be some error. Is there anything I need to do on the server? And how to setup the server? By the way, the server in this case is write using ASP running on IIS. 

Looking forward for your help! 

Thanks
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Jason don't forget to implement the **connection:canAuthenticateAgainsProtectionSpace** and **connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge** to make sure you're handling the challenges for the Server authentication and Client Authentication:

check out this post that will help you with this https://devforums.apple.com/message/143091#143091

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a public certificate. Can you access the https resource with firefox/safari/chrome without an error? if not - that's the problem, not your code.