# How to implement the ssl & https

Tags: iphone, ipad, ssl, https

Im new to this development,can any one can help me in know what is ssl and How to implement the ssl & https call

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809363/iphone-development-how-to-implement-https-connection

Answer (score 1):

For SSL check the wikipedia site: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer and for your question:

You can use the normal NSURLConnection API to access SSL pages from iOS. It's really as simple as any other URL connections - but just make sure that the certificate on the server is a public certificate - otherwise you might run into problems.

Comment: Hi magnuswat do u mean by "public certificate",which is installed on the server?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do anything on iphone. If your are accessing any server, then that server should have a ssl certificate to implement secure connection.
On iphone/ipad you just need to hit the server using NSURLConnection api and https url.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to connect to the https:// it means that you obtain a secure connection. You should study documentation for [NSURLAuthenticationChallenge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLAuthenticationChallenge_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in order to understand how to manage the certificates of the https.